# how to insert into the database without using $row

Tags: php

I am trying to insert things into the database and although I have managed to get it done, I am just wondering why the following won't work but if I assigned a variable to $row[]; first, then it will work: eg

```
$current_date = strip_tags(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
$date = strip_tags(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+5 minutes")));

$login_attempts += 1;

$sql2 = "
    UPDATE users 
    SET login_attempts = ?, login_failed_delay = ?
    WHERE user_uid = ?
";

if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2)) {
    echo 'SQL statement failed';
} else {
    //Bind parameters to the placeholder
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iss", $login_attempts, $date, $uid);
    //Run parameters inside database
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

But if I do this, then it will work:

```
$current_date = strip_tags(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
$date = strip_tags(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+5 minutes")));
$login_attempts = $row['login_attempts'];
$login_attempts += 1;

$sql2 = "
    UPDATE users
    SET login_attempts = ?, login_failed_delay = ?
    WHERE user_uid = ?
";

if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2)) {
    echo 'SQL statement failed';
} else {
    //Bind parameters to the placeholder
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iss", $login_attempts, $date, $uid);
    //Run parameters inside database
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

Comment: On your first code block your not getting the current login attempts ($login_attempts) from database. But in your second your collecting it and adding it.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you are not using any meaningful number for `$login_attempts`, so when you do

```
$login_attempts += 1;
```

It doesn't know anything about the previous value for this user.  Whereas - when you do...

```
$login_attempts = $row['login_attempts'];
$login_attempts += 1;
```

You are adding 1 to (what I assume is) the previous count of login_attempts.

Alternatively you could just add 1 in your SQL statement...

```
  $sql2 = "UPDATE users
           SET login_attempts = login_attempts+1, 
               login_failed_delay = ?
           WHERE user_uid = ?";
```

Comment: Thanks and I am trying to get the following to work but the link is showing up as text instead

Comment: $headers = 'From: '.$company;
       $txt = "Hello ".$row['user_first']."" .$row['user_last']."! \n\n Your account has been temporary suspended because you or someone claiming to be you has failed to login into their account more than on more than five occasions. \n\n Please click on the following link to change your password so that you can login again <a href='reset.php'>Click here to reset your password </a>";

        mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);

Comment: as part of my mail function for this failed login attempts

Comment: Try resetting the login_attempts on the database for the user your trying with.

Comment: Have you got any further with this?